# GAE python sdk v1.8.1 running very slow on local development

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

Since upgrading to the new SDK v1.8.1 (from v1.7.5) my local development environment has slowed down horribly (3-4x longer for most pages). The problem seems to be with the new multiple server design (all dedicated backends have their own local ip address) and with unecessary warmup calls (calls to /_ah/warmup in logging). Has anyone else had a similar issue? If so, any idea of what the fix may be?

(Currently I am renaming my backends.yaml and removing warmup for services in app.yaml as a local fix)

My backends.yaml:

```
- name: big-indexer
  class: B4_1G
  options: dynamic, public
  instances: 3

- name: indexer
  class: B4
  options: dynamic, public
  instances: 3

- name: parallel-indexer
  class: B2
  options: dynamic, public
  instances: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new server, I've found startup time is a worse, but overall perf is often better since the old server didn't use multiple cores on my CPU.

Memory usage is higher.  I'm not sure about the disk.

I'd check to see if the new server is chewing up to much RAM and thrashing the disk.